# transformation $y = u v$ transforms the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I f a transformation $y = u v$ transforms the given differential equation
$$f(x) y'' - 4 f'(x) y'+ g(x) y = 0 $$ into the equation of the form 
$$v'' + h(x) v = 0 $$ then $u$ must be

1. $ \frac{1}{f^2}  $
2. $xf $
3. $ \frac{1}{2f}  $
4. $f^2$

I am stuck on this problem. Can anyone help me please...............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take $y=uv$ we have

$$y'=u'v+v'u$$

and

$$y''=u''v+2u'v'+uv''$$

replace in equation we have

$$(f(x)u''-4f'(x)u')v+f(x)uv''+(f(x)2u'-4f'(x)u)v'=0$$

Then if we want get the equation

$$v''+h(x)v=0$$

we can assume that

$$f(x)2u'-4f'(x)u=0$$
solving this simple equaton to u

we have

$u=e^{2lnf}=f^2$,

and we get the equation desired,

$$v''+h(x)v=0$$,

where $h(x)=\frac{f(x)u''-4f'(x)u'}{f(x)u}$